# How to upgrade VirtualBox 5.0 to 5.2?

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox

I use Whonix in VirtualBox and Whonix is currently not working and I think it is because I need to upgrade VirtualBox to the newest version.

I have a lot of saved files and stuff on my Whonix computer that I can't access now. If I update VirtualBox will the files be lost?

What is the best way to upgrade VirtualBox?

Comment: It depends upon which version of Ubuntu you are running, and which method you used to install your Vbox host.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't lose your settings when you upgrade VirtualBox. If you are worried about losing your configuration or VM data, back up the "Virtual VMs" directory, Usually located at `/home/userDirectory/Virtual VMs/`

I suggest that you uninstall the package and install from the Oracle website.
Download from their webpage: https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

Uninstall using:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox-5.0
```

Install with:

```
sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.2.x.x.x.x.x-xxxxxx~Ubuntu~XXXXX_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a backup of all your virtual machines first hand.

They can be found in `/home/user/VirtualBox VMs` by default, if you can't find them, open VirtualBox, do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> and you can see the "Default Machine Folder", this is where your virtual machines are located.

Now you need to uninstall VirtualBox:

```
sudo apt autoremove --purge virtualbox*
```

Download the latest version of VirtualBox [from here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) for your distribution.

This installation should work on most Distros, so try to run:

```
sudo apt install /path/to/.deb/file/
```